# SSRS - ExecutionLog3 for ReportServer shows shared DataSet execution twice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Report has DataSets which are referring to shared datasets (takes params).

On querying

```
select top 40 * from reportserver..executionlog3
order by timestart desc;
```

I can see that the dataset executes with the same parameters twice!

Can someone please throw some light on how can I fix it.

Only those report datasets which are referring to shared datasets are shown twice in the above query output; every other individual report dataset appears only once.

Another important thing to note is that in SQL Server Profiler, I can see two calls being made to the shared-dataset-procedure but one of them is passing parameter as nvarchar and other one as string.

```
exec my_procedure @code=317
exec my_procedure @code=N'317'
```

The above SQL Server Profiler finding doesn't help. I changed the dataType of the param in both the datasets to Integer and now I can see both the procedure executions in sql server profiler with exactly same params.

Comment: The underlying data might have changed between calls to the shared dataset so it seems valid to me.

Comment: If you had 2 reports using the same shared dataset and sending it as two different data types then the cached version should be overwritten with the new one as they should be considered different.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The data is mostly static, almost no changes.

Comment: @Snowlockk I fixed the 2 dataTypes thing (the last para in the question), but still SQL server profiler shows the execution of the procedure twice. And same can be seen in ExecutionLog3.

Comment: The data might be static but SSRS doesn't know that.

Comment: Did you configure the shared dataset to be cached, as per here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149(v=sql.105).aspx. Again: the system does not know when the underlying data changes so it has no reason to use a cached version unless you tell it.